# Unexpected recursion result

Tags: python, recursion

To try to understand the Turtle Tree code, I wrote the following but this is confusing me. I would have expected the program to stop at line 2 when n=6. How is n getting reduced?

```
def num(n):
  if n < 6:
  print(n)
  num(n+2)
  print('n here is ', n)
x = 1
num(x)
```

Result:

```
1
3
5
n here is 5
n here is 3
n here is 1
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in your post.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sure the recursion does stop after n was 5 and it doesn't get to 7?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using a recursive sequence. Your n no longer reduces. The print statements simply follow afterwards when n still had the value.

Here is a schematic explanation of the sequence:

```
begin num(1)
    - print(n) # n = 1
    begin num(3)
        - print(n) # n = 3
        begin num(5)
            - print(n) # n = 5
            begin num(7)
                - ---
            end num(7)
            - print('n here is ', n) # n = 5
        end num(5)
        - print('n here is ', n) # n = 3
    end num(3)
    - print('n here is ', n) # n = 1
end num(1)
```

The order of the print calls here are logically from top to bottom.
You can see that the last print statement in the scheme still belongs to the first function call where n = 1.

Comment: I don't understand why n starts reducing.